# Can someone help decipher this seal? (Characters identified: 皇宮珍藏)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

Need help deciphering this seal. It looks to be seal script, or older than Traditional Chinese. Found on the bottom of a Dragon Turtle figurine.

[image]